# Why i got the Error like Package file was not sign correctly?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, package, google-play

I have Uploade the App on android market few days ago.
Now i have make another version of that application. I have Sign that Application with the same keystore and with the same package and Application name.
The Only things i have change is the version code of that application.
After that, On Android market i got the option of the upadte of the application.
But if i am going to update that file, the error is generate like the Package file was not sign correctly. . . So where is the problem ???
Please let me know about it. . . 
Please I realy need help. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am totally agree with @Sean Owen answer that you may have tried to upload the debug build.

Still, let me provide you additional information if you forgot to prepare release build and yes dont forget to sign this APK with the same keystore that you have signed with previously.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you changed the version name also. make sure you had done that and again try to sign the app using the same keystore and password. the problem will get solved. also make sure you have the same base package name and before.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you uploaded a debug build, rather than a release build.

Comment: how that come to know that i have uploaded the debug build or release build ?? how to fix it ?